# JENA RDF/XML format rdfs example

Tags: java, rdf, jena, rdfs

Can someone give me a **working** example (**in Java code**) of how to create a RDFS related statement like the following using Jena?

```xml
<rdf:Property rdf:about="http://www.help.me/confused/PropertyName">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.help.me/confused/ClassName"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal"/>
</rdf:Property>
```

I created a RDF/XML schema by hand, and it validates right but somehow the entities won't work together in SPARQL (even with inference engine on). So, I decided to create the whole thing from start using the Jena API to ensure that it's correct.

Comment: If it validates, but your SPARQL query doesn't run, it might be more likely that your SPARQL query has problems (and you could ask about that on StackOverflow too, but in a different question).

Comment: Also, if you're writing any RDF by hand, I'd _strongly_ suggest that you write it using Turtle or N3, which are much easier to write by hand.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It's using rdf validator not rdfs (w3 validator)... so i guess that's the first source of the problem. Secondly, I want to declare a range to be integers and I type <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"/> and my data with namespace base is: <base:has_value>50</base:has_value>, but at run time I get the warning: Error (dtRange): Property http://www.help.me/confused/has_value has a typed range Datatype[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer -> class java.math.BigInteger]that is not compatible with "50"

Comment: That sounds like a different issue (since it wasn't mentioned in the question).  The value `"50"` is a string, not an integer.  At any rate, the RDF/XML would need to specify a datatype using the `rdf:datatype` attribute, and would look like `<base:has_value rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">50</base:has_value>`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I tried to implement `<base:has_age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">50</base:has_age>` in Java but adding a property to the property won't make it. As far, I can create the property without giving it a value: `Resource integer_r = XSD.integer; Property has_age = model.createProperty(NS,"has_age"); r.addProperty(has_age, integer_r);`. Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to add a property to the property. You just
need the value of the property to be a typed literal. I've made a
point before about reading the documentation for the relevant classes
(and [you said that you did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222080/20223013#comment30164243_20223013))?

Comment: There are a bunch of entries for addLiteral in the [javadoc for Resource](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html). E.g., "addLiteral(Property p, long o) Add the property p with the typed-literal value o to this resource, ie add (this, p, typed(o)) to this's model."

Comment: You might still need to need to create a `Literal` object with your specified datatype (`xsd:integer`), though;  I don't know if any of the primitives correspond to `xsd:integer`.  In any case, this question already has an accepted answer, and you're asking a different question.  If this and the previous comment don't solve your problem, please ask it as a _separate_ question.  Questions like this in the comments don't help anyone (because they won't find them, and comments might be deleted at any time).

Comment: That's why i asked cause it had various types but int is not listed... Anyway I'll try again, experiment more, I get the vibe that you think I'm not searching before I post :)

Comment: Ints can be casted to longs, so you wouldn't have a problem there.  I don't know what datatype they get, offhand, though. Without meaning offense, it _does_ seem like you're either not reading the documentation (since you trying approaches like adding a property to a property, rather than addLiteral), or that you're not experimenting.  There's a method in Resource, "addLiteral(Property p, Object o)", and you might have tried adding objects of different types to see if any produce `xsd:integers`.  As it turns out, `int` and `long` produce `xsd:long`s, `Integer` is an `xsd:int`, but `BigInteger`

Comment: becomes an `xsd:integer`.  That is, you could do `r.addLiteral( has_age, new BigInteger( "50" ));` and get the results that you're looking for.  I agree that that's not _explicitly_ called out in the documentation, but a little bit of curiosity an exploration will go a long way.  For what it's worth, you _can_ add properties to a property, and you've _seen_ what that looks like;  it's exactly what you've done with `rdfs:domain/range` to declare the domain and range of a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the namespace a bit, just so that this code ends up pointing back to this post, but at any rate, I get this output:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <rdf:Property rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20194409/1281433/PropertyName">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20194409/1281433/ClassName"/>
  </rdf:Property>
</rdf:RDF>
```

from this code:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;

public class JenaPropertyExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String NS = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/20194409/1281433/";
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        final Property p = model.createResource( NS+"PropertyName", RDF.Property ).as( Property.class );
        p.addProperty( RDFS.domain, model.createResource( NS+"ClassName" ));
        p.addProperty( RDFS.range, RDFS.Literal );

        model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
    }
}
```

In general, just because the output is legal RDF doesn't mean that you're using the properties and classes in the way that's expected.  Jena's plain `Model` interface can't help you too much with that, since you could still use the properties incorrectly, but at least, if you're using Jena's predefined vocabulary classes, you'll get the IRIs right.  If you can use an OntModel, you can get a slightly nicer layer of abstraction, though.  E.g., the following method produces the same RDF/XML output, but lets you use methods like `createOntProperty` and get the `p rdf:type rdf:Property` triple for free, and methods like `addRange` and `addDomain`:

```java
public static void main2( String[] args ) {
    final String NS = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/20194409/1281433/";
    final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM );
    OntProperty p = model.createOntProperty( NS+"PropertyName" );
    p.addDomain( model.getOntClass( NS+"ClassName" ));
    p.addRange( RDFS.Literal );
    model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
}
```

Comment: That's so helpful, can you provide any link that uses these RDFS.Literal, RDFS.domain, RDFS.range notations (or a valid vocabulary list)? By the way, I use InfModel infmodel = ModelFactory.createRDFSModel(model); because I need inference. (I left you a comment to the OP as well if you could take a look at it)

Comment: @user2692669 The RDFS class just defines the standard RDFS vocabulary.  You can look at the [javadoc](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/RDFS.html) for a complete list, but that's just going to be the same thing as what's already in the [RDFS summary](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_summary) from the standard.

Comment: @user2692669 Whether the model is an inference model or not doesn't really affect how you could _add_ these triples to the model, so it doesn't really matter that my code doesn't use an inference model.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just tried to give you more feedback if you had anything else to add, thank you for looking at all comments.