# RDF/XML how to define RDFS classes,subclasses and link them as a type

Tags: java, rdf, jena, rdfs

How can we define classes and sub classes in Jena and add them as type of other resources after? 
I use Java,Jena and RDF/XML notation. I want to create something like:

```xml
<rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://www.help.me/NS/Classname"/>
<rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://www.help.me/NS/Subclassname">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.help.me/NS/Classname"/>
</rdfs:Class>
```

And after: linking a resource to a subclass:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.help.me/NS/NewResource">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.help.me/NS/Subclassname"/>
    ...
</rdf:Description>
```

### Edit:

As far, I found how to define a class:

```java
model.createResource("http://www.help.me/NS/", RDFS.Class);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you should read the javadoc for [Model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) and the classes and interfaces that it's related to (e.g., Resource).  You don't need to memorize all the details, but at least become familiar with the types of methods they provide, so that you've got an idea how you might accomplish something.  I'd recommend you read about [OntModel](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html) and its related classes and interfaces (e.g., Individual).

### Creating Subclasses

You can create subclass relationships by adding statements to a model directly, or by adding properties to a resource, or, if you're using an OntModel and OntClasses, with the addSubClass and addSuperClass methods.

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;

public class AddTypesExample {
    final private static String NS = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        subclassModel().write( System.out, "RDF/XML" );
        System.out.println();
        subclassOntModel().write( System.out, "RDF/XML" );
    }

    public static Model subclassModel() {
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        final Resource classA = model.createResource( NS+"A" );
        final Resource classB = model.createResource( NS+"B" );
        final Resource classC = model.createResource( NS+"C" );
        classB.addProperty( RDFS.subClassOf, classA );
        model.add( classC, RDFS.subClassOf, classA );
        return model;
    }

    public static OntModel subclassOntModel() { 
        final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM );
        final OntClass a = model.createClass( NS+"A" );
        final OntClass b = model.createClass( NS+"B" );
        final OntClass c = model.createClass( NS+"C" );
        a.addSubClass( b );
        c.addSuperClass( a );
        return model;
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- the plain Model -->
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/C">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/A"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/B">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/A"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>

<!-- the OntModel -->
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/C">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/A"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/B">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/A"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/A">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

### Adding types to a Resource (or Individual)

In this case though, you're already using some of the methods that you can use to add types to a resource, and so you've already answered your own question.  When you create a resource, you can specify a type.  E.g., to get

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.help.me/NS/NewResource">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.help.me/NS/Subclassname"/>
    ...
</rdf:Description>
```

you could do:

```java
model.createResource( "http://www.help.me/NS/NewResource",
                      model.createResource( "http://www.help.me/NS/Subclassname" ));
```

More generally, look at code like this:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF;

public class AddTypesExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String NS = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/";
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        final Resource classA = model.createResource( NS+"A" );
        final Resource classB = model.createResource( NS+"B" );
        final Resource classC = model.createResource( NS+"C" );
        final Resource classD = model.createResource( NS+"D" );

        // You can create a resource with a specified type.
        final Resource x = model.createResource( NS+"x", classA );

        // And subsequent calls to createResource will add more types.
        model.createResource( NS+"x", classB );

        // You could also add the type to the resource
        x.addProperty( RDF.type, classC );

        // Or add the statement to the model
        model.add( x, RDF.type, classD );

        model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML" );
    }
}
```

which produces as output:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:j.0="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/x">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/D"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/C"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/B"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/A"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

If you're using an OntModel, you can use `createIndividual` to create a new individual with a specified type, and you can use its `addRDFType` method to add another type, and you can also create an individual from an OntClass object:

```java
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    final OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM );
    ontModel.setNsPrefix( "so", NS );
    final OntClass classA = ontModel.createClass( NS+"A" );
    final OntClass classB = ontModel.createClass( NS+"B" );
    final OntClass classC = ontModel.createClass( NS+"C" );

    final Individual x = ontModel.createIndividual( NS+"x", classA );
    x.addRDFType( classB );
    classC.createIndividual( NS+"x" );

    ontModel.write( System.out, "RDF/XML" );
}
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/C">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/B">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/x">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/C"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/B"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/A"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222080/1281433/A">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Wow, so many ways. I created the classes but how do I create the subclasses (RDFS.subClassOf)?

Comment: @user2692669 I posted code that shows it working… Can you show your code where it doesn't work?  I bet there's something you're missing…

Comment: @user2692669 Sorry, I didn't see your first comment before I replied to your second comment.  I can update the question with how to create subclasses, but I'll point out again that this is really pretty clear in the documentation if you read through it.

Comment: Which documentation are you referring, maybe I'm looking at the "wrong" one. This is way better than the documentation (or any material on the internet to be honest).

Comment: @user2692669 I mean the Javadoc for the classes you're using.  You're clearly familiar enough with [Model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) to use some of its features.  Some of its methods return Resources, and the Javadoc links to the Resource interface, and its got a bunch of useful methods. It's almost always a good idea to at least skim the documentation/manual/etc. associated with a software library to familiarize yourself a little bit with what it contains.  You don't memorize it word for word, of course, but you read enough that…

Comment: @user2692669 …when you get to some problem, you can say "I think there was a Resource method that would handle this; let met check…".  That's not just with Jena, but with any API, software library, or tool (electronic or physical).

Comment: I did all that... but it's nice advice for everyone :)